# Sharing transaction with AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, jta, xa

I've a problem very close to this one [Sharing a transaction while using AbstractRoutingDataSource to switch datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618307/sharing-a-transaction-while-using-abstractroutingdatasource-to-switch-datasource) but I'm not able to solve using the accepted answer. I've a transactional method who have to write the same entity into two different datasource in transactional mode. When transaction commit I've a

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (VETO_PROD.SYS_C0013988) violated
```

This is my Transalctional method:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public ContactTypeJson definisciNuovaContactType(String descrizione) throws Exception {
    String functionCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5).toUpperCase();
    LOGGER.debug("Ho generato la functionCode[" + functionCode + "]");
    while (!isContactTypeAvailable(functionCode) || !notificatorService.isFunctionCodeAvailable(functionCode)) {
        LOGGER.debug("La functionCode[" + functionCode + "] e' gia' in utilizzo, genero una nuova...");
        functionCode = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5).toUpperCase();
        LOGGER.debug("...la nuova functionCode generata e' [" + functionCode + "]");
    }
    ContactType contactType = new ContactType();
    contactType.setName(functionCode);
    contactType.setDescription(descrizione);

    notificatorService.insertNewFunction(functionCode, descrizione);
    entityManagerFRVP0.flush();
    entityManagerFRVP0.clear();
    VetrinaContextHolder.setTargetDataSource(VetrinaToolConstants.FRVP_DATASOURCE);
    entityManagerFRVP0.persist(contactType);
    entityManagerFRVP0.flush();
    entityManagerFRVP0.clear();
    VetrinaContextHolder.setTargetDataSource(VetrinaToolConstants.PWVP_DATASOURCE);
    ContactType contactType1 = new ContactType();
    contactType1.setName(functionCode);
    contactType1.setDescription(descrizione);
    entityManagerFRVP0.persist(contactType1);
    VetrinaContextHolder.clearTargetDataSource();
    ContactTypeToJsonConverter converter = new ContactTypeToJsonConverter();
    return converter.convert(contactType);
}
```

This is the JPA log:

```
2013-07-15 10:47:59,570 DEBUG [sql] 2013-07-15 10:47:59.569--ServerSession(26361419)--Connection(16434777)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT VET_SEQ_CONTACT_TYPE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL 
    2013-07-15 10:47:59,581 DEBUG [sql] 2013-07-15 10:47:59.58--ClientSession(21299255)--Connection(17900213)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--INSERT INTO S_VET_CONTACT_TYPE (ID, DESCRIPTION, NAME, FASEDIDEFAULT_ID) VALUES (81, Prova doppione, 16XOV, NULL) 
    2013-07-15 10:47:59,596 DEBUG [sql] 2013-07-15 10:47:59.595--ClientSession(21299255)--Connection(17900213)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT VET_SEQ_CONTACT_TYPE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL 
    2013-07-15 10:47:59,601 DEBUG [sql] 2013-07-15 10:47:59.6--ClientSession(21299255)--Connection(17900213)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '18' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--INSERT INTO S_VET_CONTACT_TYPE (ID, DESCRIPTION, NAME, FASEDIDEFAULT_ID) VALUES (82, Prova doppione, 16XOV, NULL)
```

This the stack:

```
2013-07-15 10:47:59,421 DEBUG [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.intesasanpaolo.frvp0.alten.vetrinatool.service.console.ConsoleServiceImpl.definisciNuovaContactType]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,430 DEBUG [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Opening JPA EntityManager 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,430 DEBUG [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,483 DEBUG [TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] Adding transactional method 'findOne' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; '' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,483 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,483 DEBUG [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,483 DEBUG [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Opening JPA EntityManager 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,483 DEBUG [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,542 DEBUG [AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] Adding transactional method 'insertNewFunction' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,543 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,543 DEBUG [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,543 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,543 DEBUG [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,549 DEBUG [TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,549 DEBUG [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager' 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,550 DEBUG [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager] Participating in existing transaction 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,600 DEBUG [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,600 DEBUG [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,600 DEBUG [WebLogicJtaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit 
2013-07-15 10:47:59,827 DEBUG [DispatcherServlet] Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'jsonView'; model is {hasErrors=true, errorCode=GEN_EX, errorMessages=Errore generico} 
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is weblogic.transaction.RollbackException: Unexpected exception in beforeCompletion: sync=org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener@2f0af4

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (VETO_PROD.SYS_C0013988) violated

Error Code: 1
Call: INSERT INTO S_VET_CONTACT_TYPE (ID, DESCRIPTION, NAME, FASEDIDEFAULT_ID) VALUES (82, 'Prova doppione', '16XOV', NULL)
Query: InsertObjectQuery(ContactType [id=82, name=16XOV, description=Prova doppione, fasiAssociate={[]}, faseDiDefault=null])
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:387)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy310.definisciNuovaContactType(Unknown Source)
    at com.intesasanpaolo.frvp0.alten.vetrinatool.mvc.console.controller.CreaContactTypeController.creaNuovaContactType(CreaContactTypeController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I'm using WebLogic 10.3.5 with XA datasources and `org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are violating a unique constraint.  I assume you have one defined on the Contact name, so you cannot insert two contacts with the same name.

Trying to switch the connection under a DataSource on the fly seems like a very, very, bad idea.  Instead you should have two persistence units, one going to one database, and one going to the other.

You may also want to investigate EclipseLink's data partitioning, or composite persistence units.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Partitioning

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite

Comment: Thanks James, my goal is to persist the same entity into two different datasource...any suggest how can I approach it with Composite PU?